# Unity FindGameObjectsWithTag("taghere") returns duplicates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using FindGameObjectsWithTag("car") and I have 3 objects with the tag "car".

The method returns more than 3 objects, usually it returns 4 objects and 1 of them is a duplicate.

I can't understand it at all.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: It's "Car" not "car". A typo?

Comment: You are correct, a typo, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this using the following code;

```
foreach(Transform gObject in GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>()){
   if(gObject.tag == "car")
   {
      modelsList.Add(gObject.gameObject);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> The method returns more than 3 objects, usually it returns 4 objects
>   and 1 of them is a duplicate.

The `FindGameObjectsWithTag` function will **only** return GameObjects with the specified tag. No, it cannot return a duplicate.

There are **4** reasons why you think things aren't working properly:

**1**.You have a duplicated Object with that tag in the scene so it returns more than 3 Objects. This duplicate may be hiding or masquerading as a child of another Object. Remove the tag if so.

**2**.You mistakenly changed a tag of another GameObject to "car" and now this function is finding it. Remove the tag if so.

**3**.You are instantiating one of the GameObjects with with the "car" tag during run-time and this function can find it.

**4**. You put `FindGameObjectsWithTag("car")` in a script then attached that script to the more than one Objects. This is tricky. When you do this, you will see the-same Object twice if you use `Debug.Log` to view it. Make sure this is not the effect you are seeing. If this is the case then make sure that the script with the `FindGameObjectsWithTag("car")` code is only attached to one GameObject only.

---

You can find out if the problem is #1, #2 and #3 by using `Debug.Log` and its second parameter.

Make sure to remove your other `Debug.Log` code then attach the script below to **one empty** GameObject:

```
public class YourScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject[] obj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("car");
        Debug.Log("Length: " + obj.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(obj[i].name, obj[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Click "Play" then Click on each log from the *Console Tab* like the image below and it will highlight each GameObject `FindGameObjectsWithTag("car")` returned in the *Hierarchy*. You can use this to find hidden GameObjects mistakenly given the "car" tag then remove the tag.

[image]

---

If the problem is #4, you can use the image below to find the multiple script and remove it:

[image]

Comment: I'm going through your suggestions now.

Comment: I will accept your answer as it would be the best solutions to diagnose the issue I described. There is weird behaviour happening, I removed the tags from the 3 car model, then went to Project Settings -> Tags and Layers.. but it would not let me delete the tag and said it existed on a model I removed it from. I made no changes, ran the project and it found 1 GameObject tagged as "car". I stopped and started the project several times then it stopped finding the 1 GameObject that was tagged. It is like there is some sort of caching going on.

Comment: Don't accept when your problem is not fixed. You can un-accept it. That's fine. You can close Unity, make a copy/back of your project then delete the Library folder of your project. Run it again and see if the problem is still there. If yes, I am using Unity 2017.2beta, remove important stuff from it then send it to me and tell me how I can replicate the issue. I will see what's wrong with it

Comment: I can't give an explination and due to the randomness it is hard to replicate. It seems that when I stop and start the project too quickly it picks up models from the previous run, that is my only explination.

Comment: I would be willing to accept the answer for the amount of effort you have put in to it, and the fact that it would be the methods to resolving the issue described. My issue appears to be different to what I initially thought.

Comment: 1.Did you delete the Library folder I talked about? 2.Are you instantiating or creating any object at run-time?

Comment: Yes I have re-created the project so everything is new and all references should be correct. I have a prefab that contains 3 car model, this is loaded at run time when an ImageTarget is found.

Comment: I didn't ask you to recreate the project. I only asked you to delete the Library folder. Please , put the code in my answer after your `FindGameObjectsWithTag` function and tell the the behavior you got from that experiment I explained.

Comment: ok, I deleted the Library and put the code in after I get the objects by tag, it said Length = 1 and gave 1 car model, but in a Visual Studio breakpoint, just after your code, it says there are 7 in the car list, which comes directly from the get by tag call.

Comment: Note that I never I mentioned "Visual Studio breakpoint" in my answer. Just use what's in my answer. Click on the printed gameobject log names  **once** in the Editor and it should select object in the Hierarchy. Check that matches with how many "car" tagged objects in the Editor